# Rollback and Start Over/Pending Migration

Tags: git, migration, nitrousio

I'm new to this so forgive me if I sound like an idiot....
In my Nitrous box i keep getting a Pending Migration Error. I run the bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development, it persists. In the meantime I've tried git reset --hard HEAD to 'back out' but still getting it. Along the way I'm also getting other issues.

Can I delete or rollback the last few days worth of work and start over from where things weren't getting buggy? I git push and heroku push if that helps. I'm 3 weeks into this from Codermanual and would hate to start over, but if i have to i have to. Frustrated. Thanks for any of your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have found the commit you wish to roll back to; let's call it `ABC`. Also, am assuming that you are working on a branch called `my-branch`. Start by checking out the commit and creating a new branch: `git checkout ABC -b new-branchname`.

At this point you can just ignore `my-branch` and do all of your future work on `new-branchname`. However, if you would like to do your future work on `my-branch`, continue with the following steps:

```
git reset --soft my-branch
git commit -m "Rolling back a bunch of commits"
git checkout my-branch
git merge new-branchname
```

At that point, your code is rolled back, and you can delete the branch you created (`git branch -d new-branchname`). What's nice is that if you change your mind and/or need some code from the rolled back commits, they are still in your history.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. It's actually not on master, but a branch if that matters. I have a commit on GitHub from June 8...can I go back to that? Or do I have to look for it in Nitrous? If I do your git reset --soft master, etc, will it undo code i've added (which is fine) because honestly I want to undo what I did so I can do it correctly. I want to learn the right way before shortcuts! You're so helpful!

Comment: @JayBoucher - I edited the answer to not be specific to `master`. You can go back as far as the git history goes. Note that since git is a _distributed_ vcs, you have the complete repo with full history on the machine you work on, so you do not have to look for the changes "on GitHub". The steps I gave will indeed undo your changes, but it will not _delete_ them; you really don't want to mess around with changing history after you have already pushed your commits. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help David. With all that, still getting pending mirgtaion erros. I think I'm just going to have to trash the last 3 weeks of work and start from scratch. disappointed, frustrated and sad, but i just can't fix this. nitrous said it wasn't them and sent me here, and i feel like googling stuff is making it worse/more complicated. you've been super helpful.